# Migrate data between databases with doctrine and symfony

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I want to transfer partial data between two databases using symfony3 and docrine2,

**the scenario :**

- save an entity with relations in database 1.
- Update entity if needed in database 1.

after all modifications, I want to migrate this entity to database 2. (if exist we update if not we create it )

I use two entity managers one for database 1 and the other for database 2.

How can i do it ?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: i've tried so many solutions like 
$product = $em1->getRepository('Product')->find(1);

$em2->persist($product);
$em2->flush();

I'm trying now to work with Metadata to Update or create the entity in the target database based on data in the source database. but it's very complicated

Comment: @DanCostinel ...

Comment: You have to have an object that represents an entity declared in the second database. And for it you'll persist and flush.